# Adding configuration options to a basic JIRA gadget

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, google-gadget

This line in the [Atlassian documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/GADGETS/Allowing+Configuration+Options+in+your+Gadget) leads me to believe that simply including a `UserPref` element should be sufficient to automatically generate the UI for updating the configuration of a gadget:

> The container handles generation of the configuration UI, saves the settings and provides an API to access the settings in JavaScript.

But it doesn't seem to actually work when I create a test gadget with the following - I don't see any options when I click the "Edit" link on the gadget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs
    title="Test"
    author="Test Test"
    author_email="test@example.com"
    directory_title="JIRA Tests"
  >
  <Require feature="setprefs" />
  </ModulePrefs>

  <UserPref name="show_summ" display_name="Show Summaries?" datatype="bool" default_value="true"/>

  <Content type="html">
    <![CDATA[
        <div id="main">Test Stuff</div>
    ]]>
  </Content>
</Module>
```

Is there more to do to make that happen? I've seen a few [examples that hard-code configuration options](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/jira-issues-gadget/src/922a8ff98577129b8d37e7f6568b017d2eca2109/crucible-blockers-gadget/crucible-blockers.xml?at=master), but the above documentation suggest that you don't *have* to.

Is that something that's only available if you're [packaging it as a plugin](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/GADGETS/Packaging+your+Gadget+as+an+Atlassian+Plugin#PackagingyourGadgetasanAtlassianPlugin-StandaloneGadgetorPlugin?), or if you include some other js resource? So far I've been doing a bare plugin so I don't have access to stuff like [`#requireResource`](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/GADGETS/Using+Web+Resources+in+your+Gadget), but I'm fine with hard-coding some script elements if that's what's necessary (for now).

Sincerely stumped.

Comment: For starters, I strongly recommend downloading a copy of the [JIRA sources](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/161930/access-to-jira-source-code) and looking in `jira-project/jira-components/jira-plugins/jira-gadgets-plugin/src/main/resources/gadgets/*.xml` to see all of the gadgets that ship with JIRA itself. We do our own gadget config manually, but I suspect your missing link with the default config is that you need to construct the AJS gadget object, and in particular, supply a [config](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/GADGETS/Creating+a+Gadget+JavaScript+Object) section.

Comment: From that config URL: "config — You can use this optional parameter to define the configuration form. **If this parameter is not defined, it is assumed that the gadget has no configuration options** "

Comment: This material appears a little dated, but see also: https://docs-old.servicerocket.com/display/ATLASSIAN/Writing+an+Atlassian+Gadget From this, I think you'll need to <Require> the views feature too.

Comment: Ah, many thanks! I'll look into those configuration options, and I suppose I'll have to find the absolute path to the ajs library to keep it as a simple gadget

Comment: I suppose one of the things that threw me is the sample gadget [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/3604566) that doesn't include any other js resources (or define a config section)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly that neer worked for me eighter. I think it broke in JIRA 6..
Solution: take the javascript approach and you will be just fine. it is also way more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me, just add this script

```
<![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
var edit = window.parent.document.getElementById(window.frameElement.id +     '-edit');
edit.classList.remove('hidden');
edit.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
]]>
```